# It seems vs It seems like

Tags: grammaticality

Watching [**this video,**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NA7sYsdzZ4k) an American called Nick says, to Americans, the sentence "**It seems that**" sounds weird, but "**It seems like**" sounds more natural to Americans. Does it hold true? Most of the conversation is done in English, so please try to listen to this.

The Japanese on the right side is taught mostly by Australians so any English speakers' responses are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate question. Does this help? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97541/what-is-the-difference-between-seems-like-seems-that-seems#:~:text=Seems%20like%20is%20just%20a,complementizer%20for%20the%20tensed%20complement.

Comment: @GWarner Yes, it does help. Let me remain this question here to remember this. Thank you.

Comment: I am fine with this. I will submit an answer as well. Reject if you'd like. It's quoted from another Q&A site

Comment: @GWarner No, your answer is very welcome.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourcing another site I paraphrased their excellent answer.

> One is a more definitive statement than the other.
> One is posing the situation as a fact. The other is a possibility.
>
> "It **seems that** Bill is falling in love in with Samantha"
>
> The speaker is saying this as a fact. Even though the word 'seem' is used, "it seems that" is rather idiomatic and it means it's a fact.
>
> "It **seems like** Bill is falling in love with Samantha"
>
> It could mean one of two things but both of them are just possibilities. It's possible 'Bill is actually falling in love' is one possibility. It could also mean Bill's behavior is of a man in love. It's not possible without more context >to know which of those is being suggested by the speaker.
>
> 'It seems that' - that phraseology actually isn't heard often in the U.S. Watch an old David Nivens or Bette Davis movie and you'll hear that phrase.
> You might hear 'it seems that way.' But other than that, you won't hear 'it seems that'.

Comment: That seems right to my British ears. "It seems (that)" means "I've heard..." or "I gather..." or "apparently..."